# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > com/android/build/api/dsl/StoreArchive Error

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

I got this error while trying to run my code in flutter. How can I fix this?
I'm using the following versions:
gradle wrapper: 7.5
ext.kotlin_version: 1.7.10
gradle: 7.2.0
google-services: 4.4.0

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\DOCUMENTS\StudioProjects\samgiop_md0623\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> com/android/build/api/dsl/StoreArchive

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 31s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I've been having Build failed with an exception at Build file \android\app\build.gradle' line: 24 with different "What went wrong messages". I updated the versions of my dependencies then this is the latest error that showed up.

Comment: I have currently the same problem. Did you ever found a solution?

Comment: I'm also facing similar error messages while building and couldn't able to figure it out clearly. If anyone finds the solution happy to follow and modify it accordingly.